# Draw contours of detected objects using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, background-subtraction

I am using opencv2.4.10 with python and I am trying to draw some contours of moving objects. Unfortunately I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

First of all I use Background Subtractor from opencv (`cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`). It works fine, I can see my moving objects separated from the background.

After separation I use `cv2.FindContours` method. It also works fine and I can print contorus as list of numbers.

But then, when I am trying to draw contours on the original image frame an error occurs.

```
    cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, 1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    cv2.error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:1810: error: (-215) 0 <= contourIdx && contourIdx < (int)last in function cv::drawContours
```

Could you comment on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message we can get conditions that have to be met: `0 <= contourIdx` && `contourIdx < (int)last`

Focusing on the second part, `contourIdx < (int)last`, I'd guess that you may be trying to draw the second contour of a list that's only got either one or zero contours.